# Error in deleteSelf(): Agent should belong to some population

Tags: anylogic

I have the following model where I have a pallet agent and a box agent with a population of boxes inside the pallet agent. So pallets arrive then a forklift moves them to a table and then they enter the "delay" block that takes it to the entrance block of the Box Process. In the bottom, flowchart forklifts remove boxes from the pallets and move them to a node as shown in the picture. Once all the boxes have been removed from a pallet, a forklift takes the pallets out and they get sunk.

Currently, the removed boxes are added to a queue and they stay there. I want to remove/destroy them with a sink. When I add a sink instead of/ or after the queue I get the following error

```
Exception during discrete event execution:
root.pallets[0].boxes[-1]:
Error in deleteSelf(): Agent should belong to some population
java.lang.RuntimeException: root.pallets[0].boxes[-1]:
Error in deleteSelf(): Agent should belong to some population
```

Is there a way to get around this error. I remove the boxes from the pallets in a statechart inside the pallet agent that loops until all the boxes are removed:

```
if (boxes.size() > 0){
Box b = boxes(0);
b.box_location = this.getXYZ();
remove_boxes(b);
get_Main().enter.take(b);
current_N_Boxes--;}
```

Thank you!
[image]

Comment: this code: root.pallets[0].boxes[-1]: is not from AnyLogic, but from yourself... which means you are probably doing something before deleting which messes up everything.. who knows what that is

Comment: I pointed that out in my question. There is a population of the type Box- "boxes", inside the agent type Pallet with a statechart of the enclosed code.

Answer (score 0):

Agents flowing through a process must exist inside a population. You are removing the boxes from their population (inside the pallet agent) before trying to delete them, hence the error.

There are several ways to handle this:

1. Use Batch/Unbatch or Pickup/Dropoff blocks to 'properly' have agents inside agents with both parents and childs moving through processes at different times. (AnyLogic handles having the unbatched/dropped-off agents still existing in the default population.)
2. Create your box agents inside a master population in Main, and use collections in your pallet agents to refer to the boxes inside them. Then you can 'remove' them from the pallet (by removing them from the pallet's collection) whilst keeping them in the master population until they end their part of the process.
3. *Move* your box agents to a population in Main (say `unpalettedBoxes`) when removing them from the pallet (use the `goToPopulation` function in the box agent) and proceed as in 2.